# PHP - is this syntax possible and is it safe

Tags: php, syntax, mysqli

I have some code that isn't working yet, before I debug I want to make sure that this syntax or method can indeed work and actually **only** execute the mysql_query if the last condition is true.

Also, is this a relatively safe practice?
I couldn't find anything relating to this, I figured someone putting it in English would help clear this up for me.

```
if($var1 == $var2) {$new = 1;}
if($vara == $varb) {$old = 1;}
if($new = 1 && $old = 1) { mysqli_query($somequery);}
```

Comment: You need to double-check what the if statement in that last line is doing.

Comment: `if($new = 1 && $old = 1)` seems like a bad idea. `if($new == 1 && $old == 1)` instead ?

Comment: it'll work and its fine but you can merge it into a single `if (($var1==$var2) && ($vara == $varb)) { //do query`

Comment: This is why I always do `if (1 == $new && 1 == $old)`; if I miss a `=` I get a parse error rather than a working (albeit not as intended) script.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This won't work because of the single =.

Go for:

```
if($var1 == $var2) {$new = 1;}
if($vara == $varb) {$old = 1;}
if($new == 1 && $old == 1) { mysqli_query($somequery);}
```

Or, ideally:

```
if ($var1 == $var2 && $vara == $varb) {
    mysqli_query($somequery);
}
```

Top hint to stop things like `if ($var = 1)` typos - switch the comparisons around and put the constant first.

If you write `if ($var = 1)` then $var becomes 1 and is always true, but if you write `if (1 = $var)` you get an error, which is exactly what you want (and the same happens if your use a string `if ("yes" = $var)`.

It been hammered into us to put the variable first since forever, but you're far better off doing it the other way around.

Comment: Well, it **will** work, since 1 == true, but the problem is it'll **always** work

Comment: @ChenAsraf no, there is no point in doing an `if` using an assignment operator. `If` needs to compare stuff and not assign.

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ I know, I didn't disagree on that. Only mentioned that the if would work since an assignment of 1 will return true.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that all up. I should go with `if ($var1 == $var2 && $vara == $varb) {
    mysqli_query($somequery);
}`, right?